# ninject binding rule precedence for overlapping rules?

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

I have two questions for the scenario when I have two Ninject binding rules that overlap in scope, one more specific than the other.  They are:

- Will Ninject automatically select the most specific binding rule when constructing the object?
- Do I have to put the more specific rule before the more general rule in order of appearance in the binding rule block?

Consider the two rules below for the example:

```
// The more specific (constrained) rule that is 
// constrained to a particular class being constructued.

Bind<ISomeInterface>().To<SomeOtherClass>()
    .WhenInjectedInto(typeof(ParticularClassBeingConstructed));

// The more general rule for any ISomeInterface match.
Bind<ISomeInterface>().To<SomeClass>();
```

Comment: The first registration seems redundant. Did you perhaps mean `Bind<ISomeInterface>().To<SomeOTHERClass>();`?

Comment: @Steven - Thanks and thanks for the edits.  I've fixed the main post.  It was late at night when I posted. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first binding will only apply when injecting into `ParticularClassBeingConstructed` and the second rule will be used whenever an `ISomeInterface` is required by any other type (kind of like a default binding if a more specific one doesn't exist).

Ordering doesn't matter I don't think.

Comment: To be found in the [implementation of `BindingPrecedenceComparer`](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/KernelBase.cs), where the precedence matching functions are listed.